# Remove array inside hash

Tags: ruby

My orginal hash is like as `hash = {"sku_id"=>[4], "brand_active"=>["true"], "salesman_active"=>["true"]}`
How to remove the array within hash. that means to convert the hash like
`{"sku_id"=>4, "brand_active"=>"true", "salesman_active"=>"true"}`

Answer (score 1):

```
hash.each { |k,v| hash[k] = v[0] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
Hash[hash.map {|k, v| [k, *v] }]
```